# Google vision api localization

Tags: localization, google-cloud-vision

Is it possible to get localized results with `LABEL_DETECTION` API?

I want to show the user a result of this API, and some of my users would like to see the results in non-english.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the Vision API can return *labels* in translated form (though OCR can take in language hints).

That said, you can use the Translate API to come up with a (hopefully) decent localized version of the label name. I know that's far from perfect as translation of single words can be ambiguous, so I'm going to forward this onto the Vision team to see if there's a better answer, maybe using the Knowledge Graph API.